# Does PHP's get_defined_functions() show available functions or functions being used?

Tags: php

I just discovered the get_defined_functions() function in PHP, I was checking it out, it list all the functions.

It in addition to php's built in functions, it list 176 function I have made for my site.

I have a question about it, are all the listed functions from this being loaded, like taking up resources or is it just showing they are available if I need them?

If it just shows all functions available, is there a way to list all that are being used?

```
print_r(get_defined_functions());
```

Comment: What do you mean by "being used"?

Comment: Listing all functions your code requires to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the PHP docs](http://us.php.net/get_defined_functions):

> Returns an multidimensional array
>   containing a list of all defined
>   functions, both built-in (internal)
>   and user-defined. The internal
>   functions will be accessible via
>   $arr["internal"], and the user defined
>   ones using $arr["user"] (see example
>   below).

CliffNotes version: it gives ALL available functions in a multi-dimensional array, regardless of whether or not they've been used.

As to the second part of your question, I am unaware of any built-in PHP function that will return all used functions.

Answer (score 1):

Defined functions from scripts that are loaded for the current request, meaning if you haven't included (or required) a particular file then obviously it's functions won't be defined.

See [`get_defined_functions()`](http://au.php.net/get_defined_functions).

**Note:** functions defined by `create_function()` are not returned.